# Overwriting package function with assignInNamespace

Tags: r

I am trying to overwrite a function from the `grid` package `assignInNamespace` to allow me to use a list as its argument.

From

```
> vpList
function (...) 
{
    vps <- list(...)
    vpListFromList(vps)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000016dc0671a90>
<environment: namespace:grid>
```

To

```
vpList <- function (vps) 
{
  grid::vpListFromList(vps)
}
```

It seems to work:

```
> assignInNamespace("vpList",vpList,ns="grid")
> grid::vpList
function (vps) 
{
  grid::vpListFromList(vps)
}
```

but I get an error when I try to use it:

```
> n <- c(viewport(name= "a"), viewport(name ="b"), viewport(name = "c"), viewport(name = "d"))
> vpTree( viewport(layout=grid.layout(2,2), name = "body"), grid::vpList(n))
Error: 'vpListFromList' is not an exported object from 'namespace:grid'
Called from: getExportedValue(pkg, name)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `grid:::vpListFromList`

Comment: Fantastic! Learned something today.

Comment: Suggestion:  don't do that.  Since your function does something different from the regular one, name it differently.

Comment: @user2554330 Great point!